# Neo4J Merge a Node if a property exist and create another node with relationship

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I have a Document Node with properties `documentId`and `name`. I need to create multiple Activity node such that each of the activity is related to Document with `CONTAINS` relationship as follows as

`Document-CONTAINS->Activity`

Now in Neo4J I want to write a query such that it will merge Document Node if it exists or Create if it doesn't. And in the same query it creates an Activity with `CONTAINS` relations ship.

Something like below

```
merge (d:Document{documentId:100,name:'Doc1'})-[r:CONTAINS]->(a:Activity{name:'ijk'})
return d, a
```

When this query runs for the first time it will create `Document` and `Activity` Node and it will also create `CONTAINS` relationship.

When I run the same query with different Activity name, it should create new `Activity` Node and `CONTAINS` relationship and it should merge `Document` node.

I want to do this in one single query.

Comment: So far I have been able to create a document node separatly with query `create (d:Document{documentId:100, name:'Doc1'}) return d`. And then I have used the MERGE query such that it only creates new Activity node and CONTAINS relationship using query `MATCH (d:Document {documentId:100, name:'Doc1'}) Merge (d)-[:CONTAINS]->(a:Activity{name:'ijk'}) return d, a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, just separate your node and relationship creation.

```
merge (d:Document{documentId:100}) on create set d.name='Doc1'
merge (a:Activity{name:'ijk'})
merge (d)-[:CONTAINS]->(a) 
return d, a
```

if your activities are not globally unique, then you can MERGE them in the context of the document

```
merge (d:Document{documentId:100}) on create set d.name='Doc1'
merge (d)-[:CONTAINS]->(a:Activity{name:'ijk'})
return d, a
```